# perl hash of hash of arrays with looping

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have the following data in a hash of hash of arrays.  The numerical data in the array represents that last 4 quarters of financial information.

I'd like to be able to iterate over the array, and pull out the data by quarter, to get it ready to insert into a database.  With my code below I can get all of the quarters, or one quarter only if I specifically call it.  When I try and add another loop to iterate over the hash of hash of arrays to return only the array subset values, i get all the values and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  See code:  Thanks for the help

```
my %comp_info = (
  CompanyA => {
    COGS    => ["175.00", "155.00", "125.00", "125.00"],
    Revenue => ["300.00", "200.00", "250.00", "225.00"],
  },
)
```

```
# The following works, but I have to specifically push one array subset at a time, 
# which makes passing values to db_insert subroutine ineffective.  
# (Id have to have 4 or 5 calls depending on number of quarters of data in each record).

sub get_insert_arrays {
  foreach $comp (keys %comp_info ) {
     foreach $column ( keys %{$comp_info{$comp}} ) {
        push (@insert_array, @{$comp_info{$sym}{$column}}[0] );
     }
  }
  my $valuelist = join(", ", @insert_array);
  &db_insert($valuelist);
  undef @insert_array;
}
```

```
#try to loop through, fails, I get all of the data in @insert_array instead of only one quarter.
sub get_insert_arrays {
  foreach $comp (keys %comp_info ) {
     foreach $column ( keys %{$comp_info{$comp}} ) {
        for my $i ( 0 .. $#{$comp_info{$comp}{$column}} ) {
           push (@insert_array, @{$comp_info{$sym}{$column}}[$i] ); 
        }
     }
    my $valuelist = join(", ", @insert_array);
    &db_insert($valuelist);
    undef @insert_array;  
    undef $valuelist;   
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Your first example gets all the first quarter figures, while the second example gives you all of the figures. I don't understand what other option there can be. By the way, you should `prepare` an SQL statement that uses placeholders and pass the values in to the `execute`, rtaher than building an SQL statement piecemeal.

Comment: I want to know if I can construct this in such a way as to produce a loop that will give me the first quarter figures, I pass that into the db_insert, then the second quarter figures, pass that into db_insert, and so on...

Comment: Why do you need to represent the source data in memory using hashes of hashes? Why can't you just use SQL to read it?  E.g. if you pull the data from a CSV file, you can use DBD::CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend to dereference with intermediate variables, and also using the `->` syntax. Both of these help you figure out what's going on:

Here's your first subroutine using dereferencing:

```
sub get_insert_arrays {
    my @insert_array;

    foreach $comp (keys %comp_info ) {      # References to a hash (Revenue, COGS)
        %columns = %{ $comp_info{$comp} };  # Dereference
        foreach $column ( keys %columns ) { # Reference to an Array (quarter data)
            my @values = @{ $column } ;     # Dereference
            push (@insert_array, $column );
            my $valuelist = join(", ", @insert_array);
            &db_insert($valuelist);
        }
    }
}
```

Hmm... Looking at this, it's easy to see that I can simply do:

```
    for my $comp (keys %comp_info ) {      # References to a hash (Revenue, COGS)
        %columns = %{ $comp_info{$comp} };  # Dereference
        for my $column ( keys %columns ) { # Reference to an Array (quarter data)
            my @values = @{ $column } ;     # Dereference
            db_insert(@values);
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to see a particular piece of data, use the `->` syntax to simplify your structure:

```
${$comp_info{$sym}{$column}}[$i];   # You had "@". Should be "$".
```

vs.

```
$comp_info{$sym}->{$column}->[$i];
```

Much easier to read.

Also use the `warnings` and `strict` pragmas in your program. It'll catch a lot of errors that may include undefined variables, and misspelled variable names.

If you're pulling out data *quarter-by-quarter*, you probably want the ***COGS*** to be with the ***Revenue*** column:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#

use strict;             # Lets you know when you misspell variable names
use warnings;           # Warns of issues (using undefined variables
use feature qw(say);

#
# Just initializing the data you had
#
my %comp_info = ( CompanyA => {
        Revenue => [
            300.00, 200.00, 250.00, 225.00
        ],
        COGS => [
            175.00, 155.00, 125.00, 125.00
        ],
    },
);

#
# Go through each company
#
for my $company ( keys %comp_info ) {
    my @revenues = @{ $comp_info{$company}->{Revenue} };  # Dereference
    my @cogss    = @{ $comp_info{$company}->{COGS} };     # Dereferenec
    say "Company: $company";
    #
    # I know the keys are "Revenue" and "COGS", so I don't need a loop.
    # I'll just go right to my quarters data. Note that dereferencing
    # makes my program a lot easier to write and maintain
    #
    for my $quarter ( (0..3) ) {
        my $revenue = $revenues[$quarter];
        my $cogs    = $cogss[$quarter];
        my $profit = $revenue - $cogs;
        say "    Quarter: " . ($quarter - 1)
             . " Revenue = $revenue  COGS = $cogs Profit = $profit";
    }
}
```

How you do your database inserts is up to you. But, you can see how doing a bit of dereferencing and using `->` can clarify what you're looking at.

---

### Addendum

> how do I pull out just the quarter by quarter data without having to specify revenue, cogs, etc. in some cases there could be 30+ fields, so I don't want to have to specify each field in the program. I just want to grab all Q1 fields, insert, grab all Q2 field, insert, etc.

So two loops:

- Like before, I have my outer loop go through for each company which just happens to be the key for that `%comp_info` hash.
- Each *value* in the `%comp_info` hash is a reference to another hash that is keyed by the data type (COGS, Revenue, etc.). Again, I simply loop through the keys of that inner hash (after dereferencing to make it easier to understand).
- Now that I have the company name (the key to that `%comp_info` hash, and a list of the keys in that inner hash, I can simply pull up the first quarter numbers for each company and each data type. Getting the quarter value is simple: `$comp_info{$company}->{$type}->[$quarter]`. Note that there is three levels of data, and I have three sections in my variable with each section separated by `->`.

  - I can see that the outer most section is a simple hash that's keyed by the company name: (`$comp_info{$company}`).
  - This `%comp_info` hash points to a hash reference (`->{type}`) which is keyed by the data types  (COGS, Revenue, etc.).
  - And that hash reference points to an array reference for each quarter (`->[$quarter]`). See how that works and why I like that `->` syntax? It makes it very clear what I am working with.
  - This is just the first quarter results. If I wanted to go through each and every quarter, I could have an outer loop `for my $quarter (0..3) {`.

Here's what it looks like. This is a complete program, so you could cut this out, and try running it yourself and see if you can figure out what's going on.

```
use strict;             # Lets you know when you misspell variable names
use warnings;           # Warns of issues (using undefined variables
use feature qw(say);

my $quarter = 0;        #First Quarter is 0. Last quarter is 3
my %comp_info = ( CompanyA => {
        Revenue => [
            300.00, 200.00, 250.00, 225.00
        ],
        COGS => [
            175.00, 155.00, 125.00, 125.00
        ],
    },
);

for my $company ( keys %comp_info ) {
    say "Company: $company";
    %types = %{ $company_info{$company} };
    for my $type ( keys %types ) {   # COGS, Revenue, etc.
        say "   $type for quarter " 
            . ($quarter + 1) . ": "
            . $comp_info{$company}->{$type}->[$quarter];
    }
}
```

One more time for each quarter to insert the data into your database:

Using `use strict` and declaring variables with `my` means that variables are only valid for a limited scope. That `my @type_data;` declares a array that holds my type values for inserting into your database. However, since it's declared inside that `for my $quarter`  loop, the array and its values disappears with each iteration of the loop. No need to have to remove the data or reinitialize the variable. It does it all by itself!

Look up how [Lexically Scoped Variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my()) work.

```
for my $quarter ( (0..3) ) {
    my @type_values;
    for my $company ( keys %comp_info ) {
        my %types = %{ $comp_info{$company} };
        for my $type ( keys %types ) {   # COGS, Revenue, etc.
            push @type_values, $comp_info->{$company}->{$type}->{quarter};
    }
    insert_data( @type_values );  # Database insert you wanted
}
```

Comment: `$comp_info{$sym}{$column}[$i]`

Comment: I like the `->` because it adds some spacing between the various elements of the structure and makes it a bit easier to read. Plus, it's a reminder that this is a reference.

Comment: Fair enough. I just think it's a lot more legible than `${$comp_info{$sym}{$column}}[$i]`, which I had to look at for a moment to be sure it meant the same thing.

Comment: David, thank you too.  So if I've used Tie::Hash to preserve hash order, then how do I pull out just the quarter by quarter data without having to specify revenue, cogs, etc.  Right now I just want to get the data into the database and later I'll pull it out and do operations against it.  But in some cases there could be 30+ fields,   so I don't want to have to specify each field in the program.  I just want to grab all Q1 fields, insert, grab all Q2 field, insert, etc.

Comment: That question I just asked wasn't clear.  I'm not asking about Tie::Hash, I should have said I used it so I don't have to be concerned about the column order when I pull it from the hash of hash of arrays.  Its preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Your recent addition - `undef @insert_array; undef $valuelist;` is a misuse of `undef`. Putting it *before* a variable like that forces a garbage collection cycle, which is something you don't want to do -- it is best to let Perl look after things itself.

Arrays should be emptied with `@insert_array = ()` rather than using `undef`, and for scalars you should `$valuelist = undef`. But these variables are irrelevant outside the subroutine, so you should declare them *inside*, in which case there is no need to reinitialise them in the first place.

Please bear in mind what I said about calling `prepare` on an SQL statement with placeholders. Your code should look something like this

```
my $insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO table VALUES (?, ?)');
```

and later

```
my @insert_array = (175.00, 300.00);
$insert->execute(@insert_array);
```

However I have written this, which I think does what you want, to create a `$valuelist` string as your own code does. Since you don't need the hash *keys*, it is much tidier to iterate over the *values* instead. The `db_insert` subroutine is a dummy that just prints the values of the parameter passed to it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %comp_info = (
  CompanyA => {
    COGS    => ["175.00", "155.00", "125.00", "125.00"],
    Revenue => ["300.00", "200.00", "250.00", "225.00"],
  },
);

my @values = map values %$_, values %comp_info;

for my $i (0 .. $#{$values[0]}) {
  my @insert = map $_->[$i], @values;
  db_insert(join ', ', @insert);
}

sub db_insert {
  say "db_insert('@_')";
}
```

**output**

```
db_insert('175.00, 300.00')
db_insert('155.00, 200.00')
db_insert('125.00, 250.00')
db_insert('125.00, 225.00')
```

---

**Update**

To comply with the new specification:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %comp_info = (
  CompanyA => {
    COGS    => ["175.00", "155.00", "125.00", "125.00"],
    Revenue => ["300.00", "200.00", "250.00", "225.00"],
  },
  CompanyB => {
    COGS    => ["175.00", "155.00", "125.00", "125.00"],
    Revenue => ["300.00", "200.00", "250.00", "225.00"],
  },
  CompanyC => {
    COGS    => ["175.00", "155.00", "125.00", "125.00"],
    Revenue => ["300.00", "200.00", "250.00", "225.00"],
  },
);

my @columns = qw/ COGS Revenue /;

for my $comp (keys %comp_info) {
  my $data = $comp_info{$comp};
  for my $i (0 .. $#{(values %$data)[0]}) {
    my @values = ( $comp, map $_->[$i], @{$data}{@columns} );
    db_insert(join ', ', @values);
  }
}

sub db_insert {
  say "db_insert('@_')";
}
```

**output**

```
db_insert('CompanyC, 175.00, 300.00')
db_insert('CompanyC, 155.00, 200.00')
db_insert('CompanyC, 125.00, 250.00')
db_insert('CompanyC, 125.00, 225.00')
db_insert('CompanyA, 175.00, 300.00')
db_insert('CompanyA, 155.00, 200.00')
db_insert('CompanyA, 125.00, 250.00')
db_insert('CompanyA, 125.00, 225.00')
db_insert('CompanyB, 175.00, 300.00')
db_insert('CompanyB, 155.00, 200.00')
db_insert('CompanyB, 125.00, 250.00')
db_insert('CompanyB, 125.00, 225.00')
```

Comment: Borodin, thank you, I have a couple of questions.  First, why in the for loop if I print "$valuelist\n"; do I only see the i = 0 instance?     Also, I guess I should have made this clear but what if I have multiple companies in the array?  The print of valuelist shows all of them joined together in one list.

Comment: I don't know. If all you've done is add the `print` statement then there's no reason. And regarding multiple companies, I wrote a solution that does the same as your own. You will have to say what you want to get an answer. There's also no way of knowing whether the `COGS` or the `Revenue` value will come first.

Comment: Ok fair enough.  Assume a hash with multiple companies, and I want to insert into the database a list of a companies info, so company name, and the COGS and revenue values, by quarter.  So I have separate DB tables by quarter.  Same example as above, Just including CompanyB, CompanyC, etc.   I can use the value of $i to pass a parameter to DB to identify which table the values are being inserted into.

Comment: And I'll check on the placeholders on the DB insert.

Comment: Finally to make it more clear, I would call the db_insert for every company info that I pull out of the hash, i.e. Insert into comp_info_Q1 values ('CompA', 350, 175);  Or its possible to do multiple record inserts, but the record values still need to be separate by company.

Comment: Okay I've written an update. No, you can't insert multiple records using `DBI`. You really should look at `prepare` and placeholders, as it's much more secure that way, and it automatically quotes your values for you correctly, according to data type, so there's no need to mess about with the SQL string.

Comment: Ok, so one more question, assuming the real dataset has perhaps 20 to 30 columns, is there a way using your method to get them without having to pass the columns (hash keys) in the {qw / COGS Revenues /};   For example, get the list of columns, pass them into an array or string, and then quote the array or string?  i.e. {qw / $col_list /};

Comment: @user2482575: Take a look at my modified solution.